# sql, adding to table with a value coming from another table

Tags: sql, insert

So I have table A and table B.
I insert a entry into table A and this will generate a id in table A.
Now I want to use this id to insert another entry in table B.
The entry I am creating in table A has a unique field I can search to get the entry I created.
Thanks for all who try to help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
INSERT INTO table_b
(column1, column2, etc)
VALUES
(
    ( SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE unique_column = 'value' LIMIT 1 ),
    value2,
    etc
)
```

As an alternative, if you're using PHP you can use [mysql_insert_id](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) or a similar function to get the ID that a row was inserted into table A with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little cleaner?

```
INSERT INTO table_b
SELECT
  id,
  value2
FROM table_a
WHERE unique_column = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

***If using PHP:***

I guess when you say "this will generate an id", you mean the column is AUTO_INCREMENT so the id will be set by MySQL.

Then you should use `mysql_insert_id()` or `PDO::lastInsertId` with PDO.

That should then look like :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_A ...");
$last_id_in_table_A = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_B (id_table_A) VALUES ($last_id_in_table_A)");
```

Comment: He doesn't specify that he's using PHP. He may be, but it's just tagged SQL, so this could be entirely irrelevant :)

Comment: It's very easy to forget that there are other combinations. A couple of times I've posted unwittingly on a SQL Server question with MySQL syntax, it can be a right bugger if you're not properly awake heh